# PostgreSQL: Joining with Window Function / Partial Table

Tags: postgresql, join, window-functions, cross-product

**Issue**

I'm working a project with kernels in databases, and my PostgreSQL skills have hit a wall. I am joining between two tables to compute the cross product, i.e.

```
SELECT (d1.a * d2.a + d1.b * d2.b) AS dot FROM data d1, data d2
```

This gives me the cross product between all vectors. Having the following data in my table

```
 a | b | c 
---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 2
 3 | 3 | 3
```

The above command yields

```
 dot 
-----
   2
   4
   6
 ...
```

*If I want to compute the dot product between, say, row 2 with its preceding row and its following row, how would I do that efficiently?*

**Attempts**

I have tried to use window functions, but failed to do so since they only compute aggregate functions. I want to join a row with its neighbouring rows (i.e. its window), but not compute any aggregate over these. Something along these lines:

```
SELECT a * a + b * b + c * c
    OVER(rows between 1 preceding and 1 following) as value FROM data data;
```

I have also tried to use `row_number() OVER()` which works. But this seems clumsy and inefficient with nested subqueries.

```
SELECT d1.a * d3.a + d1.b * d3.b + d1.c * d3.c 
    FROM data d1, 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT *, row_number() OVER() as index from data) d2 
    WHERE d2.index >= 1 AND d2.index <=3) d3;
```

Lastly, I tried to dig into `LATERAL`s with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to define preceding and next.  SQL has no notion of such constructs.  Also, sample results would help explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: `... compute the dot product between, say, row 2 with its preceding row and its following row,` Please define *preceding* and *following*. (define *order* and your problem will be solved) BTW: does your table have a Primary Key?

Comment: Assume that we have any arbitrary order, in the example, say on the column `a`. How would I do a join between a, and itself and n adjacent rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the values of preceding/following rows by `lag()`/`lead()`.
If the order of rows is determined by `a`, the query would be like:

```
SELECT
  a,
  (lag(a, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY a)) * (lead(a, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY a))
  + (lag(b, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY a)) * (lead(b, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY a))
  + (lag(c, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY a)) * (lead(c, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY a)) AS dot_preceding_and_following
FROM ( VALUES
  (1, 1, 1),
  (2, 2, 2),
  (3, 3, 3)
) T(a, b, c)
ORDER BY
  a
;
```